# Getting "too few connections" in full tezos-node with Octez 11.0

Tags: node

I recently started getting "too few connections" errors on my full node running the latest 10.x release, after not having issues for months.
I thought it might have something to do with the 11.x upgrade, so I upgraded to 11.0 but I'm getting the same issues.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Here's the error I'm getting:

[image]

Here's my config:

[image]

FYI, I double-checked and my `listen-addr` (port 9733) is open.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have `min-connections` set to 300 and your node says it only has 161. The message in the log is printed based on these two numbers. Simply lower your `--connections` and the messages will stop.

If you want to connect to more nodes, use the well known [addpeers.sh](https://gist.github.com/utdrmac/2125a8514960e163837e86bc934f19b6) script in a cron job to keep you "topped up".

OCAML is not a multi-threaded language. The more connections you maintain, the more CPU/memory the node will require just to maintain these connections. If you are a baker, this will impact your ability to parse/apply new blocks.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! I think I copy-pasted most of that config from other posts here  Also, `addpeers.sh` looks very useful